# counter example about convergence in distribution

Tags: probability

I'm looking for a counter example of the following statement. The fact that $X_n$ and $X$ are random variables such that $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$  in distribution does not ensure $\mathbb{E}(X_n) \to \mathbb{E}(X)$. But I cannot find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $\mathrm P(X_n=n)=1-\mathrm P(X_n=0)=1/n$.

Comment: +1: to make it even clearer, $\Pr(X_n=0)=\frac{n-1}{n}$ so the convergence in distribution is to $Pr(X=0)=1$ wheich has $E[X]=0$